# How to appropriately format a research paper in pragmatics for applying to a master's program?

Tags: pragmatics, applied-linguistics, discourse-analysis

Dear fellow linguists,

I am just an enthusiastic undergraduate student applying for a MA in Applied Linguistic. I have a couple of questions and I need some advice from those of you who are 'in the know' about what goes on in the academic world. The university I'm applying for has listed a bachelor thesis under the admission requirements, but the program I am currently studying in does not include a bachelor thesis. I was told I could submit "an equivalent sample of written work" or an independent research project as a replacement for the thesis.

I decided to do a study of pragmatic competence of EFL learners of English at my university, so I designed a WDCT and administered the survey to 60 students, and found about 10 native speakers as a control group. It's not really a proper cross-sectional nor cross-cultural study because the student groups do not necessarily consist of students who have the same level of knowledge in English, and I didn't find enough native speakers to do some sorts of a statistical analysis. I assumed that because the study program implies progression of language skills from B1 to C1 over the two years, that students' pragmatic competence should also increase over the course of studies (of course, it hasn't).

Here are my questions (I asked for formatting guidelines from the university, didn't get any specific requirements except for an 8,000 word count):

1. What is the best way to treat and represent the data in this scenario? (raw, percentages?)
2. What would be the best way to format the paper? I was thinking about APA, but it would be too much paper to send abroad (which is not cheap, as it is measured in grams, and making it double spaced would make it about 30 pages long or so)?
3. How should I name my sections? APA says not to have an Introduction as the title of the introduction, but some (published) papers have clearly marked sections of the paper.
4. Is it appropriate to acknowledge the professor who was kind of like my mentor during this research, and what is the best way to do it?

Thanks to all of you who took the time to read this, I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: 1. I'd recommend summarising the results in the main body, and then including the raw data as an appendix. 
2. If you can avoid sending a hard copy, APA and double spaced is the way to go. Single spaced would probably be OK, but not ideal. Weigh up the costs/benefits.
3. I like to use numbered sections and sub-sections so that the logical structure of my argument is as clear as possible. We're writing scientific papers, not essays.
4. It's important to acknowledge your prof. One convention i've seen is using an initial footnote on the title of the paper as an acknowledgements section.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I will use modified APA then, single spaced with numbered, clearly marked sections. I did think it was odd APA recommended against giving explicit names to sections, that seems to make the paper look more like an essay.

Comment: No problem. Given that you're submitting a term paper as part of an application, rather than an article to a journal, i wouldn't worry too much about following APA's guidelines to the letter. As long as your formatting is clear and consistent, it should be fine! Good luck with your application.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about formatting a research paper.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly modified re-posting of my comment on the original post, so we can get this classed as answered and out of the way:

1. It's common practice to summarise the key results within the main body of the paper (graphs are always good), and then give the actual raw data in an appendix so that interested specialists can follow up any specific queries.
2. If you can avoid sending a hard copy, APA and double spaced is the way to go. Single spaced would probably be OK, but not ideal. Weigh up the costs/benefits.
3. I personally like to use numbered sections and sub-sections so that the logical structure of my argument is as clear as possible. We're writing scientific papers, not essays. I imagine that certain journals don't approve of this, but since you're not submitting to a journal it shouldn't be an issue.
4. It's important to acknowledge your professor, and anyone else who's contributed to the paper. One convention i've seen is using an initial footnote on the title of the paper as an acknowledgements section.